# how to define qml GroupBox title style

Tags: qt, qml

```
    GroupBox {
        title: qsTr("I want to change my style")

        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
```

I want to change the title's color or size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **setForegroundRole ( QPalette::ColorRole role )** for changing the title color or **setFont ( const QFont & )** for changing the font size.

Comment: where in the qml should this be? can you post a short example please?